# Package (Python PIL/Pillow) installed but I can't import it

Tags: python, pip, package, python-imaging-library

I want to do some image processing and I encountered a problem. Importing the pillow module doesn't seem to work. I found a simple script here to check what packages are installed and I found it, but importing it doesn't seem to work.

Here's the code I'm trying to run:

```
import pip

installed_packages = pip.get_installed_distributions()
installed_pillow_packages = [
    "%s==%s" % (i.key, i.version)
    for i in installed_packages
    if "pil" in i.key.lower()
]
print(installed_pillow_packages)

import pillow
```

And here's the result:

```
runfile('C:/Users/Augustas/.spyder2/temp.py', wdir=r'C:/Users/Augustas/.spyder2')
['pillow==2.6.1']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 601, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 66, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/Augustas/.spyder2/temp.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pillow
ImportError: No module named pillow
```

I'm running this on Windows 8.1 using Spyder and Python 2.7.9.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are importing incorrectly. Try using:

```
import PIL
```

or

```
from PIL import Image
```

`PIL`, i.e., Python Imaging Library is no longer maintained, `Pillow` is used instead. To maintain backwards compatibility, the `PIL` module name is used in imports.

Answer (score 5):

In fact, Pillow is installed under name "PIL", so:

```
import PIL as pillow
from PIL import Image
...
```

Look this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the doc:

http://pillow.readthedocs.org/handbook/tutorial.html

You must import it like that:

```
import PIL
```