# Import problems python [PILLOW]

Tags: python, module, pycharm, importerror, python-imaging-library

I want to `import pillow` module but have some problems. I did  **pip install PillowModule.whl** , downloaded from this [site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pil)

And through  [PyCharm module install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YT9Zq.jpg) 
but when I try to import it I get error `ImportError: No module named 'Pillow'`

Any advice is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pillow is a fork of PIL an older python imaging library

to import Pillow, you do the following:

```
from PIL import Image
```

edit: this stackoverflow problem [Package (Python PIL/Pillow) installed but I can't import it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30547931/package-python-pil-pillow-installed-but-i-cant-import-it?rq=1)

is worth a read.