# Import Error: Pillow 3.3.1 & Python 2.7 & El Capitan OS

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I have installed the Pillow package from PIP using `pip install Pillow` and Pillow 3.3.1 got installed. I am working with Python 2.7 on Mac OS 10.11 (El Capitan).

When I try to import the Image module, I run into `ImportError: No module named Pillow`. I tried to import the following:

- `import Pillow`
- `import Image`
- `import Pillow.Image`

All return the same `ImportError`.

What is missing?

Comment: Did `pip` install to the right Python installation…?

Comment: What is the specific import error that you are getting?

Comment: try `from PIL import Image`

Comment: Yes pip installed correctly with no errors.

Comment: Pillow has an alias it is PIL. Strange but that' s a fact.

Comment: Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import Pillow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named Pillow

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Package (Python PIL/Pillow) installed but I can't import it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30547931/package-python-pil-pillow-installed-but-i-cant-import-it)

Comment: trying from PIL import Image, results in ImportError: No module named PIL

Comment: do you have another python install? Try `which pip`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: still getting "ImportError: No module named PIL"

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: which pip results in: /usr/local/bin/pip

Comment: @Kamoly: try `pip --version` and `which python` please.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, pip --version: pip 8.1.2 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7), and which python: /usr/bin/python

Comment: don't you have to `sudo pip install Pillow` on macosx?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, I did install it that way. It is correctly installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reinstall package properly using `python -m pip install package_name`

Then import using `from PIL import Image`.

Comment: Unfortunatly no, it results in: ImportError: No module named PIL

Comment: Cython==0.24.1
Django==1.9.6
image==1.5.4
mysql-connector-python==2.0.4
mysql-connector-python-cext==2.1.3
MySQL-python==1.2.5
mysqlclient==1.3.7
nose==1.3.7
numpy==1.11.1
Pillow==3.3.1
PyMySQL==0.7.9
requests==2.11.1
scipy==0.18.0
unicodecsv==0.14.1
virtualenv==15.0.1

Comment: try installing one more time, this time use this command `path_to_your_python_executable -m pip install package_name`

Comment: thanks Laszlowaty, I did install it with your command, and it can import PIL now.