# ModuleNotFoundError when I `import pillow`

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to use pillow however pip claims to have downloaded it already yet it will not run. Here is my console:

```
➜  Downloads pip3 install Pillow
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-    packages
Requirement already satisfied: olefile in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-    packages (from Pillow)
➜  Downloads cat code.py
import pillow
➜  Downloads python3 code.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pillow
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pillow'
➜  Downloads
```

Thanks as always for the help

Comment: `import Pillow`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Package (Python PIL/Pillow) installed but I can't import it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30547931/package-python-pil-pillow-installed-but-i-cant-import-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should still `import PIL` but not `pillow`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem as far as I can see is that

```
import pillow
```

is not used by Pillow to import the library.

Based on their documentation - http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.3.x/handbook/tutorial.html - you should use:

```
import PIL
```